# Bundles vs. line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, line-bundles

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and consider the category $\text{Bun}$ of (finite dimensional) vector bundles over a $K$-variety $X$. Consider also the category of $\mathbb{G}^\times$-principal bundles over $X$, $\text{Bun}_0$. $\mathbb{G}^\times$-principal bundles are equivalent to maps into $\mathbb{P}^{\infty}$, and with this I have a much clearer picture of how $\text{Bun}_0$ works in algebraic geometry e.g. with the clutching construction.

However, the cohomology classes in algebraic geometry are more typically understood as being valued in $\text{Bun}$ (not just $\text{Bun}_0$). Somehow it is possible to extend from the case for line bundles so long as $l_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus l_n$ is sent to $\text{cl} (l_1) \cup \cdots \cup \text{cl}(l_n)$. I see of course that such an extension is unique when it exists, but I do not as of yet understand why we can consistently extend maps from $\text{Bun}_0$ to $\text{Bun}$.

So my question is, what is an extension theorem that goes something like this (ideally with a reference):

> A natural transformation from $\eta : \text{Bun}_0 = \text{Bun}_0(X) \implies F$ between contra variant functors on $K$-varieties always extends to a natural transformation $M(\eta) : \text{Bun} \implies F$ preserving the apparent product structure given by $* \rightarrow X \leftarrow X \times X$.

Comment: This is called the splitting principle. A reference is \[[Weibel, The K-book](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook.html), Chapter 2, p33, Chern splitting priciple].

Comment: @Z.M, I think that [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439210/bundles-vs-line-bundles#comment1132821_439210) is an answer!

Comment: @Z.M yes- post it in a box to get [credit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credit).